# Find merged cell in Excel, split the cells and write those in new spreadsheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have been given a Assignment that I need to Split the data of a Spreadsheet and Write it into the new Spreadsheet. The Conditions are, Given Spreadsheet may have multiple numbers of Merged Cells and I need to find those Merged cells and write those Data in a New SpreadSheet.
ie, the data or cells between one merged cell till  to another Merged cell must be written in another Spreadsheet.

My Code of Effort is given below,

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;


public class CopyTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CopyTest excel = new CopyTest();
    excel.process("D:\\B3.xls");
 }

public void process(String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(bis);
    HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = null;
    HSSFRow row = null;
    HSSFCell cell = null;
    HSSFSheet mySheet = null;
    HSSFRow myRow = null;
    HSSFCell myCell = null;
    int sheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
    int fCell = 0;
    int lCell = 0;
    int fRow = 0;
    int lRow = 0;

    for (int iSheet = 0; iSheet < sheets; iSheet++) {
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(iSheet);
        if (sheet != null) {
            mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet(sheet.getSheetName());

            fRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
            System.out.println("First Row at"+fRow);
            lRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            for (int iRow = fRow; iRow <= lRow; iRow++) {
                row = sheet.getRow(iRow);
                myRow = mySheet.createRow(iRow);



                if (row != null) {
                    fCell = row.getFirstCellNum();
                    lCell = row.getLastCellNum();
                    for (int iCell = fCell; iCell < lCell; iCell++) {
                        //if (mySheet.getMergedRegionAt(index)!=null)
                       System.out.println("Finding next merged Cells");
                       cell = row.getCell(iCell);
                        myCell = myRow.createCell(iCell);
                        if (cell != null) {
                            myCell.setCellType(cell.getCellType());

                            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                myCell.setCellValue("");
                                break;

                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                myCell.setCellValue(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                                break;

                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                                myCell.setCellErrorValue(cell.getErrorCellValue());
                                break;

                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                                myCell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula());
                                break;

                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                myCell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                break;

                            case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                myCell.setCellValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            default:
                                myCell.setCellFormula(cell.getCellFormula());
                               // System.out.println("Reading Cell value\t"+myCell);
                            }System.out.println("Reading Cell value\t"+myCell);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }  

    bis.close();
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("D:\\Result Excel1.xls", true));
    myWorkBook.write(bos);
    bos.close();

 }}
```

With this Code, I have Achieved cloning the spreadsheet into another new Sheet. Here, I am failing to find the merged Cell, getMergedCellRegionAt() helps me and returns merged cell region like A:4 D:12 like that. how do I proceed with this. Kindly Help me, your small effort is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Javadocs for `HSSFSheet`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getMergedRegionAt%28int%29), `getMergedCellRegionAt()` was deprecated in 2008 because the `Region` it returns was also deprecated, in favor of `CellRangeAddress`.  It suggests that you should use [`getMergedRegion(int)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getMergedRegion%28int%29) instead, which returns a `CellRangeAddress`.

The merged region data is not stored directly with the cells themselves, but with the `Sheet` object.  So you do not need to loop through rows and cells looking for whether they are part of a merged region; you just need to loop through the list of merged regions on the sheet, then add the merged region to your new sheet with [`addMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#addMergedRegion%28org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress%29).

```
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
{
    CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
    // Just add it to the sheet on the new workbook.
    mySheet.addMergedRegion(mergedRegion);
}
```

These methods on `HSSFSheet` are in the [`Sheet`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html) interface, so they will work with any Excel workbook that Apache POI supports, .xls (HSSF) or .xlsx (XSSF).

Comment: Correct answer. Just to make the answer complete: there is also the possibility of using `getMergedRegions()` which returns a list of `CellRangeAddress`.

Answer (score 4):

#### The merged cells have their value in the first cell.

The following method returns the value of the region provided the first cell's row and column in the merged region

```
String getMergedRegionStringValue(HSSFSheet sheet, int firstRow, int firstColumn){
   for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
        CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);

        int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn();
        int rowNum = region.getFirstRow();
        //check first cell of the region
        if(rowNum == firstRow && colIndex == firstColumn){  
            return sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

rgettmans answer is completely correct.

### Java 8

I just wanted to add a solution for Java 8 with streams:

```
Sheet oldSheet, newSheet;
IntStream.range(0, oldSheet.getNumMergedRegions())
           .mapToObj(oldSheet::getMergedRegion)
           .forEach(newSheet::addMergedRegion);
```