# Fetch data from Excel file having merged cells and store in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, excel, vba

I have an Excel file of normal cells along with merged cells and a task to store each row in the Excel file to MySQL database. I am able to get data of each cell from Excel file and store in the database except data from merged cells. My java code:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("/Users/test.xlsx");


        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for(i=0;i<no.ofrows;i++)
for(j=0;j<no.ofcolomns;j++)
{
  String var = String.valueOf(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check [Sheet#getMergedRegions() and Sheet#getMergedRegion(int index)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getMergedRegions%28%29) JavaDoc.

Comment: How to get data from Merged region is it in the normal way or any other way is there

Comment: Pardon! Is it a question? Since merged regions are handled differently than the usual cells you may need to develop a solution to read cell and range addresses in order to read the content in the order it is displayed.

Comment: Can you provide any sample code or any resource that can manage (get data from)normal cells as well as merged cells

Comment: How do you obtain no.ofrows and no.ofcolumns values in your example?

Comment: Deepika's answer should be working for you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29673497/4211402 . And yes it works even there is no merged columns.

Comment: That doesnt work for a sheet having both merged cells and normal cells i have tried before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93371/discussion-between-izce-and-labeo).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link; [HOW TO READ A NEW EXCEL SHEET](http://javahabit.com/2014/04/18/apache-poi-tutorial-reading-writing-excel-files-java/) for a tutorial to read excel xlsx files.