# Read value in Excel file which is a single value within multiple cells

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I need to extract data from an Excel sheet in Java which is generally not a problem. I have a special case for which I couldn't find a good page.

I have a single value, yet this value is in 4 rows. For example, `value = 25`, but `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and `A4` together display that value.

The Apache POI version is 3.6. I couldn't find a good method to do this. Could someone someone point me in the right direction. Obviously `row.hasNext()` will not work in this.

Is there a method or an approach?

Comment: Do you mean you have a merged cell? if so, just read A1

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664977/how-to-read-from-merged-cells-of-excel-in-java-using-apache-poi

Answer (score 1):

For merged cells, the value is stored in the **top left cell**.

For example, if the cells `A1`, `A2`, `B1` and `B2` are merged, the value is present in the cell `A1`.