# How to Determine Merged Cells range for a given excel sheet using docx4j?

Tags: java-8, docx4j

I wanted to read an excel sheet that has one merged column and I need to treat that column to determine the rows that are grouped with. So that I can consider that group as a set. Likewise each merged rows are considered as set1, set2, set3 and so on. I will then process each set w its rows separately.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
As Requested by @fireandfuel, I am including the approche that I have arrived.

```
    CTMergeCells mergeCells = workSheet.getMergeCells();
    SheetData sheetData = workSheet.getSheetData();
    List<ArrayList<Row>> rowGroups = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Row>>();
    List<CTMergeCell> cTMergeCells = mergeCells.getMergeCell();
    for(CTMergeCell mcells : cTMergeCells){
        String range = mcells.getRef();
        Integer rowStart = Integer.parseInt(range.substring(1, 2));
        Integer rowEnd = Integer.parseInt(range.substring(4, 5));
        ArrayList<Row> rowss = (ArrayList<Row>) sheetData.getRow().stream().filter(row -> {
            return row.getR() >= rowStart.longValue() && row.getR() <= rowEnd.longValue();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        rowGroups.add((ArrayList<Row>) rowss);
    }
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: @sidgate  I have tried only  `formatter.formatCellValue(row.getC().get(3))`. I do not know what to be called to get the rows range as we do in [Apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664977/how-to-read-from-merged-cells-of-excel-in-java-using-apache-poi). I went through the docx4j documentation but no luck.

Comment: You might be interested in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to review your code. I see some issue with your approach, but it's off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to access the definition of merged cells in `SpreadsheetML` using docx4j.

`Office Open XML` files (docx, xlsx and pptx) are simply ZIP archives which are containing XML files. You can open it with the most archive programs and have a look inside its file structure and files.

Here is some source code for to access the definition of merged cells using docx4j:

```
// load yourFile.xlsx file
SpreadsheetMLPackage spreadsheetMLPackage = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(new File("yourFile.xlsx"));

// get worksheet from /xl/worksheets/yourSheet.xml file from yourFile.xlsx
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart) spreadsheetMLPackage.getParts().get(new PartName("/xl/worksheets/yourSheet.xml")); 
Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.getJaxbElement();

// get the merged cells
CTMergeCells ctMergedCells = worksheet.getMergeCells();
if(ctMergedCells != null){
    List<CTMergeCell> mergedCellList = ctMergedCells.getMergeCell();
    // do something with the merged cells
}
```

The class `org.xlsx4j.sml.CTMergeCell` has a function `getRef` which gives you the reference of cells which are merged as `String`, encoded as `begin:end`, like `A1:B2` (merged cells from `A1` to `B2`: `A1`, `A2`, `B1` and `B2`).

Comment: Thanks and I am able to achieve the same, but `getRef` gives only `String` and with this I need to do more manipulation to get the `List<Row>` with in that range. Do we have and other way to do the same? `    String range = mcells.getRef();
`    Integer rowStart =` `Integer.parseInt(range.substring(1, 2));`
`    Integer rowEnd =` `Integer.parseInt(range.substring(4, 5));
    ArrayList<Row> rowss = (ArrayList<Row>) sheetData.getRow().stream().filter(row -> {
     return row.getR() >= rowStart.longValue() && row.getR() <= rowEnd.longValue();
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @SathishKumarkk As docx4j only provides an low level API for the access on `Office Open XML` files you have to implement the function on your own. Please edit your question and add your approach(es) to your question. PS: After having a quick look over your approach, it only works as long the column token is less than 27 (column 27 is `AA`). An alternative to it might be a XPath query on the data, but be warned that it might change the document structure!