# Excel formatting with Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi

I have an excel file in the following format:

[image: Input format]

I would like to restructure this format and have it outputted in the following format:

[image: Output format]

The sections are repeating and can appear in any order but they will have either format. The 'Check' column is sometimes merged across rows as shown in the image.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Fairly easy concept. Too bad you aren't showing us you tired. Good luck!

Comment: I have googled/ bing'ed and baidu'ed this issue but have no conclusive outcome. If anyone can help then it would be great.

Comment: Everything we would think of and probably advice you might not be of use to you. Simply because that would not work. In order that to work, we must have **something real**. If you tried anything, please post it. the code that you already have might give us necessary details.

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529467/find-merged-cell-in-excel-split-the-cells-and-write-those-in-new-spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Guava's Table](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) as a data structure to save reinventing the wheel

A few caveats;

- There may well be some mathematical trick with matrices or pivot
  tables or functional programming that may do the same job with much
  less code.
- I'm not sure if I'm using the latest and greatest POI classes for this
- I have gone for brute force and many data iterations but hopefully it should be easy to follow.
- I've assumed that it is practical for you to identify the ranges
  of cells that define the data (ABC, XYZ, etc.)
- I guessed that the first row and column of a merged area would always
  contain the actual value (I don't know if this is always the case)
- The code could easily be optimized with final variables etc.

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable;
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class ExcelFormatting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("Data.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        // ABC - Range A3:F7 in Data.xls
        Table<Integer, Integer, String> abc = getValues(sheet, 2, 0, 6, 5);
        //displayTable(abc);
        // XYZ - Range A11:E14 in Data.xls
        Table<Integer, Integer, String> xyz = getValues(sheet, 10, 0, 13, 4);
        //displayTable(xyz);

        Table<Integer, Integer, String> results = HashBasedTable.create();
        // Headers
        results.put(0, 0, "Name");
        results.put(0, 1, "Section");
        results.put(0, 2, "Check");
        results.put(0, 3, "Cat");
        results.put(0, 4, "Value");
        // Process ABC table
        results.putAll(transform(abc, "ABC", results.rowMap().size()));
        // Process XYZ table        
        results.putAll(transform(xyz, "XYZ", results.rowMap().size()));
        displayTable(results);
    }


    private static Table<Integer, Integer, String> transform(Table<Integer, Integer, String> table, String section, int offset) {
        Table<Integer, Integer, String> results = HashBasedTable.create();
        int maxRows = table.rowMap().size();
        int maxCols = table.columnMap().size();
        // First col is Name
        String name;
        // Second col is Check
        String check;
        String catA, catB, catC, catD = null;
        // offset is added so that table putAll doesn't overlap data rather than append it
        int outputRow = 0 + offset;
        for (int r = 0; r < maxRows; r++) {
            name = table.get(r, 0);
            check = table.get(r, 1);
            if (check == null) {
                check = "";
            }
            catA = table.get(r, 2);
            catB = table.get(r, 3);
            catC = table.get(r, 4);
            if (maxCols == 6) {
                catD = table.get(r, 5);
            }
            if (catA != null) {
                results = addRow(results, outputRow, name, section, check, "A", catA);
                outputRow++;
            }
            if (catB != null) {
                results = addRow(results, outputRow, name, section, check, "B", catB);
                outputRow++;
            }
            if (catC != null) {
                results = addRow(results, outputRow, name, section, check, "C", catC);
                outputRow++;
            }
            if (catD != null) {
                results = addRow(results, outputRow, name, section, check, "D", catD);
                outputRow++;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    private static Table<Integer, Integer, String> addRow(Table<Integer, Integer, String> table, int row, String name, String section, String check, String category, String value) {
        table.put(row, 0, name);
        table.put(row, 1, section);
        table.put(row, 2, check);
        table.put(row, 3, category);
        table.put(row, 4, value);
        return table;
    }

    // Convert "merged" data into normal populated cells
    private static Table<Integer, Integer, String> getValues(Sheet sheet, int minRow, int minCol, int maxRow, int maxCol) {
        Table<Integer, Integer, String> table = HashBasedTable.create();
        String result;
        Row row;
        Cell col;
        int r = minRow;
        int c;
        while (r <= maxRow) {
            row = sheet.getRow(r);
            c = minCol;
            while (c <= maxCol) {
                col = row.getCell(c);
                result = getValue(sheet, row, col);
                if (result != null) {
                    table.put(r - minRow, c - minCol, result);
                }
                c++;
            }
            r++;
        }
        return table;
    }

    private static String getValue(Sheet sheet, Row row, Cell cell) {
        String result = getCellValue(cell);
        if (result == null) {
            result = getMergedAreaValue(sheet, row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String getCellValue(Cell cell) {
        String result = null;
        if (Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cell.getCellType()) {
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
        }
        if (Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cell.getCellType()) {
            result = cell.getNumericCellValue() + "";
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String getMergedAreaValue(Sheet sheet, int row, int col) {
        int mergedAreas = sheet.getNumMergedRegions();
        CellRangeAddress mergeArea;
        for (int i = 0; i < mergedAreas; i++) {
            mergeArea = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
            if (mergeArea.isInRange(row, col)) {
                return getCellValue(
                        sheet.getRow(mergeArea.getFirstRow())
                        .getCell(mergeArea.getFirstColumn()));
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void displayTable(Table<Integer, Integer, String> table) {
        int maxRows = table.rowMap().size();
        int maxCols = table.columnMap().size();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String val;
        for (int r = 0; r < maxRows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < maxCols; c++) {
                val = table.get(r, c);
                if (val != null) {
                    sb.append(val);
                }
                sb.append("\t\t");
            }
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }


}
```

This should result in the following output:

```
Name    Sect    Check   Cat     Value       
QQQ     ABC             A       1.0     
QQQ     ABC             D       5.0     
WWW     ABC     X       B       2.0     
WWW     ABC     X       D       5.0     
EEE     ABC     X       C       3.0     
EEE     ABC     X       C       4.0     
RRR     ABC             D       6.0     
QQQ     XYZ             A       1.0     
QQQ     XYZ             C       4.0     
WWW     XYZ     X       B       2.0     
WWW     XYZ     X       C       4.0     
WWW     XYZ     X       B       3.0     
WWW     XYZ     X       C       4.0     
EEE     XYZ     X       C       4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer below link.It contains all types of thing which can be done using apache poi api.Its a documentation of that.

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html