# Cant find merged cell in excel with java

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to retrieve a value from a cell in excel but it is merged.  I am using Java

This is what i have:

```
        ByteArrayInputStream bxf = new  ByteArrayInputStream(entity.getAttachment().getFile());
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(bxf);
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Row cpRow = sheet.getRow(4);
```

Here is the example of the excel:

Red Block is a merged cell :

[image]

## edit

I am using apache.poi library

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529467/find-merged-cell-in-excel-split-the-cells-and-write-those-in-new-spreadsheet or

Comment: You need to specify which library are you using and what is wrong with this code

Comment: And what is your problem? I only see a screenshot and code that gets a row?

Comment: I am getting a Null Pointer exception

Comment: `getRow` is 0-based, you probably want `getRow(3)` .

Comment: So, the real thing here: please spend some time at the [help], and read for example about creating [mcve] input. Sorry to say that, but your question is missing essential elements, and I have no clue who would upvote something like this (in its current form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why you getting a null pointer are that the value you are looking at currently is the actual row 5 on sheet.

As stated by @Berger in the comment the 'getRow is 0 based'

Use getRow(3) instead.

Please see https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html

aswell as

it states https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html

HSSFRow getRow(int rowIndex)
Returns the logical row (not physical) 0-based.